# Не получается получить access_token VK API PHP

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api

Необъяснимое происходит на последнем пункте, в котором я пытаюсь получить access_token через полученный code. 
Вот пример запроса, который выходит:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=CLIENTID?%D1%81lient_secret=CLIENTSECRET&code=fcc8e8abdc7a0500c9&redirect_uri=http://localhost/test/login.php
```

Вот код:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
if(empty($_GET['code'])) header("location:/test/index.php");
else
{
  @$apitoken = File_Get_Contents("https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id={$appid}?сlient_secret={$appkey}&code={$_GET['code']}&redirect_uri={$redirect_uri}");
  $apitoken = json_decode($apitoken, true);
  $_SESSION['apitoken'] = $apitoken['access_token'];
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $apitoken['user_id'];
  header('location: /test/index.php');
}
?>
```

Что при работе кода, что вручную получаю одну и ту же ошибку:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"client_secret is undefined"}
```

Я менял приложения, их типы. С десяток раз проверял истинность client_secret
В чём дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед сlient_secret должен быть амперсанд, а стоит знак вопроса. Из-за этого параметр теряется